# How to export 3D pointcloud data in HDF5 datasets to .ply file format

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, hdf5, point-clouds, h5py

Given a HDF5 file, having complete_pcds of type HDF5 datasets under it as shown below.

[image: HDF5 file structure]

This complete_pcds is sort of like an array wherein each row contains data for one 3D model. I want to convert each row of this complete_pcds into a .ply file, with the aim of viewing it as 3D model eventually. Including the complete_pcds file's properties for reference.

[image]

Comment: What is a .ply file? Can you describe the format? It's easy enough to read the HDF5 data. The only challenge is formatting it into the desired file format.

Comment: polygon only version (.ply files) and .pcd file formats are the once that are used to store 3D pointcloud data. Can we do it in 2 steps: 1)generating a .txt file by reading the rows of complete_pcds from the HDF5 file and 2) and then converting the .txt file so obtained to .ply file. Any suggestions would be valuable

Comment: Is there a reference for .ply and .pcd file formats? Also, what is the format (dtype) of the `complete_pcds` dataset? It's found on General Object Info tab under Dataset Dataspace and Datatype (or you can get as the ,dtype attribute with Python/h5py). BTW, do you care which language is used (Python, C/C++, FORTRAN, ?)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've edited and added an image containing datatype and properties of the complete_pcds file. So far as language is concerned, there are no language restriction because mainly I'm aiming for my final output as .ply file. Also as a reference for the .ply/.pcd file format do u expect a detail description about those formats??

Comment: May be we can read one row and make txt file containing that row. Then convert that txt file to pcd file. Your thoughts!!

Comment: Going from the HDF5 data directly to a .ply file is straight forward. There is no need to create an intermediate file. (I have not researched .pcd, but assume it's similar.) Your dataset only has floats. I assume these are vertices (points). Do you have faces (elements) defined somewhere? Or do you just want the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at an answer. I'm still a little fuzzy on your data and schema.
Your screen shot shows shape of `(2400, 2048, 3)`. From this I assume you want 2400 output files, each with 2048 vertices, where x,y,x coordinates are the values from the dataset [file#,vertex#,0:2]. Also, your file doesn't have any element face definitions, so they are not created. If this is correct, read on...if not please correct/clarify my assumptions.

Also, I created a simple HDF5 to test. The code to create it is at the end of the answer. The example has 4 rows of data; each row has 8 points that define the corners of a cube (and the cube in each row is scaled - 1st row is 1x1x1, 2nd row is 2x2x2, and so on).

Here are references I used for ply format:

- [PLY - Polygon File Format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/)
- [File Formats - PLY file](https://docs.fileformat.com/3d/ply/)

**Code to extract data to .ply file:**

```
import h5py
filename = 'MVP_Train_CP_ex.h5'
with h5py.File(filename,'r') as h5f: 
    ply_ds = h5f['complete_pcds']
    print(ply_ds.shape, ply_ds.dtype)
    for cnt, row in enumerate(ply_ds):
        v_cnt = row.shape[0]
        with open(f'pcds_{str(cnt)}.ply','w') as ply_f:
            ply_f.write('ply\n')
            ply_f.write('format ascii 1.0\n')
            ply_f.write(f'comment row {cnt} exported from:{filename}\n')
            ply_f.write(f'element vertex {v_cnt}\n') # variable # of vertices
            ply_f.write('property float x\n')
            ply_f.write('property float y\n')
            ply_f.write('property float z\n')
            ply_f.write('end_header\n')
            for vertex in row:
                ply_f.write(f'{vertex[0]:#6.3g} {vertex[1]:#6.3g} {vertex[2]:#6.3g}\n')
```

**Code to create example file:**

```
import numpy as np
import h5py 
filename = 'MVP_Train_CP_ex.h5'
with h5py.File(filename,'w') as h5f: 
    vertices = np.empty(shape=(4,8,3))
    for i in range(vertices.shape[0]):
        vertices[i,:,:] = (i+1)* np.array([ \
                    [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                    [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                    [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                    [ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]])    
    
    ds = h5f.create_dataset('complete_pcds',data=vertices)
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience and effort. Can you please remove the comment right after the header (ply_f.write('comment start of vertex list \n')), as because of this line I'm unable to render the 3D file so created in 3D viewer softwares and there is an error thrown. As soon as that line gets removed it works like charm. Following which I'll be able to accept your answer.

Comment: Interesting....comments should be ignored. I will. Note: You can delete the line from the code.

Comment: Yeah the comments after the header should be avoided. Thanks:)